# Is it possible to run unstripped binaries which loads unstripped libraries present in LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: c, linker, segmentation-fault, environment-variables, embedded-linux

In my target ARM embedded system, all applications and the dependent libraries are available only as stripped versions. Most of the binaries are present in /bin, /usr/bin paths and libraries present in /lib, /usr/lib path are all stripped.

But with these I was not able to run **Valgrind** and **GDB**. As both needs debug symbol information which is present in non-stripped version. So, I copied all the non-stripped (bins and libs) from my dev server to target system in a different path say(**/tmp/test**)

```
Bins -- /tmp/test/usr/bin, /tmp/test/bin
Libs -- /tmp/test/usr/lib, /tmp/test/lib
```

When I tried to run the **unstripped binary**, the process snmp_agent got crashed.

```
$LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/test/usr/lib/:/tmp/test/lib/ /tmp/test/usr/bin/snmp_agent -p 8000 &
```

Even I tried running **dynamic linker** as below but this time linker crashed.

```
$/tmp/test/lib/ld-2.24.so /tmp/test/usr/bin/snmp_agent -p 8000 &
```

Coredump when doing **export** and executing non-stripped bin:

```
root@myway:~# export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/test/usr/lib/:/tmp/test/lib/; /tmp/test/usr/bin/snmp_agent -p 8000 &
[1] 21218
root@myway:~#
[1]+  Segmentation fault      (core dumped) /tmp/test/usr/bin/snmp_agent -p 8000
root@myway:~#
```

Getting coredump for **default linux cmds** after export:

```
root@myway:~# ls
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
root@myway:~# env
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
root@myway:~# pwd
/home/root
root@myway:~# date
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Thanks @*nidhoegger* suggestion to use strace.
Found that I **missed symlink version** of libs with **strace** output:

```
open("/tmp/test/usr/lib/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/tmp/test/lib/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\20=\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=427500, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 491640, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x76351000
mprotect(0x763b8000, 65536, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0x763c8000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x67000) = 0x763c8000
close(3)                                = 0
```

Symlink lib in regular **system lib path**(stripped):

```
root@myway:~# ls -l /lib/libm.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Jun 22 11:30 /lib/libm.so.6 -> libm-2.24.so
```

I didnt copy the **symlink** version of unstripped libs to my path **/tmp/test/usr/lib** and **/tmp/test/lib/**

```
root@myway:~# ls -l /tmp/test/lib/libm.so.6
ls: /tmp/test/lib/libm.so.6: No such file or directory
root@myway:~# ls -l /tmp/test/lib/libm-2.24.so
-rwxrwx---    1 root     root       4885456 Jun 22 20:15 /tmp/test/lib/libm-2.24.so
```

Likewise my unstripped program is trying to load nearly 30 dependent libraries(verified this using **ldd** also) and all of which doesn't have symlink to original lib file. So the lack of **symlink file** is the reason behind the crash?

Comment: Usually I use `export $LD_LIBRARY_PATH...` I think exporting makes the updated value available to other processes.

Comment: @kiner_shah - Once I do `export`, execution of even default linux cmds like `ls, env,..`  generates coredumps(**SEGFAULT**).

Comment: The command should look like this: `export $LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/test/usr/lib/:/tmp/test/lib/; /tmp/test/usr/bin/snmp_agent -p 8000 &` Notice the `;` used to separate the two statements. Not sure if that will solve the issue, but that's how I run export command followed by an exe in a single command.

Comment: Run ldd on your executable to see what else it is picking up.  If you are on hpux10, use chatr.

Comment: could you post the exact error message and the output of strace?

Comment: Try using `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/test/usr/lib/:/tmp/test/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. This will ensure that the previous value is also used in case the required libraries aren't found in those two paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So the lack of symlink file is the reason behind the crash?

No, the reason behind the crash is that your unstripped binaries are coming from a different build.

If the difference was *only* due to stripping, you would be able to mix and match stripped and unstripped binaries freely, but you clearly can't.

The reason why *all* parts of GLIBC (the loader `ld-linux`, `libc.so.6`, `libpthread.so.0`, `libdl.so.2`, etc) must match exactly (must come from the same build) is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617).

Answer (score 1):

You're effectively creating a partial chroot environment, and there are several tools which would probably help you in this situation, however I'll describe the algorithm that I use when doing this by hand.

Start with the binary, and the run-time loader that is used with the file. You already have a `bin` and `lib` subdirectory structure. Copy the `ld.so` into the lib directory, and the binary into the bin directory. Then start with this command:

```
env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/test/lib:/tmp/test/usr/lib /tmp/test/lib/ld.so --list /tmp/test/bin/snmp_agent
```

It will give output like this (this is from a completely different system):

```
host$ /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --list /bin/ls
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x0000037433fc7000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x0000037433958000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000037433567000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00000374332f5000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00000374330f1000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000037433da2000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000037432ed2000)
```

Any libraries that are not found, or are referencing host libraries, and not libraries under `/tmp/test/{lib,usr/lib}` are ones that should be copied into `/tmp/test/lib`.

Repeat until there are no unresolved libraries.

For execution, you do:

```
env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/test/lib:/tmp/test/usr/lib /tmp/test/lib/ld.so /tmp/test/bin/snmp_agent -p 8000
```

Next comes the 'runner' - I generally rename the binaries to binary.real, and keep them all in a *single* bin directory (this makes the script a lot easier) - you would need to adapt this runner if you choose to keep a `bin` and `usr/bin`, an use the following:

```
#!/bin/bash -p

dir=$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")
env LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$dir/../lib:$dir/../usr/lib" "$dir/../lib/ld.so" "${0}.real" "$@"
```

Now you put copies/links of this file for all the programs you want to run.

If you're ld.so is newer than v2.33, then you can use the `-argv0` option when invoking the `ld.so` directly to give it the proper argv0 name:

```
env LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$dir/../lib:$dir/../usr/lib" "$dir/../lib/ld.so" -argv0 "$0" "$0.real" "$@"
```